# Upgrade database objects while they are still being used by an application

Tags: database, oracle

I like a solution to upgrade database objects in an oracle database, like alter table, update package by a newer version, etc... while these objects are still used in an application on a production server.

I heard of continuous integration but this is not what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know of a solution to upgrade these objects?

Maybe you can mention a version or so and then when you use it call the version you want to use or so.

I'm looking for a solution made by oracle and not invent my own ofcourse. I know I can invent stuff to do something like that but thats not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name was correct but didn't post it as an answer.

All this can be achieved by using edition-based redefinition of oracle.

[More info on Edition-Based Redefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS99916)

With this option you can make editions of packages and views en put them in production at the moment all your testing is done without going offline.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Oracle Change Management Pack](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96679_01/overview.htm)

There is a [Oracle create schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm) construction to make DDL changes transactional

I think there is nothing to keep different versions of the same package like ;# in SQL Server stored procedures. Even ORACLE, when back compartability is not supported, abandon old packages and creates new ones.

Adding columns to the tables should be transparent, you would have to rebuild depending views an procedures, but it is more or less automatic. New columns would not appear in views even if you used *. Records in procedures would contain new column only if they are declared as %ROWTYPE.